# MongoDB - Sorting by Reference or 'Foreign Key' (Liftweb, Scala)

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift, mongodb-scala

I have a user which contains a reference field "o" which points to an organisation:

```
> db.users.findOne()
{
"o" : ObjectId("4ec3548544ae1b7234548826")
}
```

Organisations contain a field "n":

```
> db.organisations.findOne()
{
    "n" : "My organization" 
}
```

I want a list of users sorted by o.n, preferably in Scala / Lift.

Comment: That won't work. If you can select all users, you can sort application-side, if not you may want to look at denormalization and duplicate the organisation name in the user records.

Comment: Ouch.. that's unfortunate.. :-/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are effectively asking for is a JOIN. MongoDB has no notion of a JOIN.

From the server's perspective, collections simply don't know about each other. Some tools abstract this away (like Morphia), but there are really only two basic ways to make this happen:

1. **Manual join**: load the `users`, then load the `organizations`, merge them together and join client-side.
2. **Denormalize**: store a copy of the N field inside of the `users` collection (and keep it in sync). This will make your query work fast, but it will complicate updates.

This lack of JOINs is one of the fundamental MongoDB trade-offs. If this is a common query or essential query, you either have to do #1, #2 or #3: pick a different DB.

Comment: or #4: find a way to get your application working without the sort.

Comment: This is no longer true as of version 3.2: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup

Comment: try sorting 500.000 docs by its relation's field with limit of 10 docs. i can't understand why this is so painful.